# move (not scroll) to anchor point using javascript, in function where elements are being hidden / unhidden

Tags: javascript, anchor, single-page-application

I have a small app, where in the same page, I am using JavaScript to hide an unhide elements by adding and removing the hide class, in order to make it look like you are going to a new page. The trouble is that it doesn't always take you to the top of the new 'page'. I have been told the smartest way is possibly to use an anchor point. I don't want any smooth scrolling or anything, as it is supposed to look like you have gone to a new page. There seems to be loads of people n here advising how to do fancy scrolling animation, but all i want is for the view to snap to the correct bit of the page. I only have the one anchor point, currently.

A typical bit of my JavaScript where I need to add a 'move to anchor' bit of code;

```
$("defects_found").click(function() {
  if (check_checklist()) {
    $("#identify_defects").removeClass("hide");
    $("#check_defects").addClass("hide");
    $("#nil_defects").removeClass("was_pressed");
    $("#defects_found").addClass("was_pressed");
    $("#details_text")[0].required="true";
    $("#select_defects_error1").addClass("hide");    
  } else {
    $("#select_defects_error1").removeClass("hide"); 
  }
});
```

Whichever elements are hiden / unhidden, I want to move to the same anchor point at the top of the page. I have my anchor point placed just under the html for my navbar;

```
<a class="scroll" name="anchor"></a>
```

Comment: What did you try? Be more specific. We are not going to write your code.

Comment: Baszz - I have spent all day trying to find a bit of code on here that would allow me to simply snap to an anchor point using JavaScript in a function. I haven't found anything at all (as I have said previously; there is lots of stuff I don't understand that relates to smooth scrolling etc and how not to get it to jump but that isn't what I want). Not knowing anything really about JavaScript except how to add and remove classes, I tried; 'scrollTo

Comment: I tried; 'scrollTo('#anchor'); as part of the JS function, and I also tried to do this alongside event.preventDefault(); as I figured I might need to do that. Other answers on here lead me to try; $('html','body').animate(scrollTop:$this.hash).offset().top} and elsewhere; function scrollToAnchor(aid){ var aTag = $("a[name='"+aid+"']"); $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow'); } but I dont really understand any of that...

Comment: If anyone could provide me with example code where they have done this (as simple as possible and without smooth scrolling or any animation other than a basic move / snap), that would be great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instant scrolling (no scrolling animation), set the `scrollTop` property of the element with the scrollbar.  In this case, it sounds like you want `document.body.scrollTop = 0;`.

Comment: Thanks Brilliand :) Your name is very apt. That was all I needed. I knew it must be something really simple, but couldn't find it anywhere. You're a star!